# Searching a HashMap<String, Arraylist<Users>> or HashMap<String, HashSet<Users>>

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I need to search through a `HashMap` that contains a key/value of either `String, ArrayList<Users>` or `String, HashSet<Users>` for a given value. I am unsure how to write the code to do this in java.

I declared..

```
private HashMap<String, ArrayList<Users>> cm = new HashMap<>();
```

my method that needs to be called to search looks like this...

```
public void doSomething(User u, String product) {

}
```

so I'm unsure of how the code inside the method would work.

```
if (cm.containsKey(product) {
   //This is where I'm unsure if I find the key on how to check if the ArrayList has a 
   particular user. And then if not how to add them.
}
```

Comment: Your code is not syntatically correct. Can you please post your real code here please

Comment: Further, your question is vague. Please tell what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `User` addition method could look like this:

```
public void doSomething(User user, String product) {
   if (cm.containsKey(product)) {
      List<User> list = cm.get(product);
      if (!list.contains(user)) {
         list.add(user);
      }
   }
}
```

This assumes that you define your `HashMap` with a single `User` type:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<User>> cm = new HashMap<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how to do it, but I asked a question a few days ago concerning map entry sets and using '?' to allow multiple types.  The answer I accepted was well explained and comes with an example.  Might help you out.

[Trouble understanding Java map Entry sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12983478/trouble-understanding-java-map-entry-sets)